# LUKS: How can I add more password slots (or remove/change a password)

Tags: boot, partitioning, password, encryption, luks

**luks** offers up to 8 password slots (=multiple passwords which are valid at the same time).
Installing Linux I face the problem

- how to add a new password slot
- how to remove a password slot
- how to see how many slots are active
- how to test if a password is valid for a container/partition
- how to backup the header of a luks partition (=data live insurance...)

Which commands would help me do this job?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I assume that the partition is `/dev/sda3`
If you don't know the name you can list all partitions with `lsblk -f`.

**Add a new password slot:**
`sudo cryptsetup luksAddKey /dev/sda3`

- The next free password slot will be used
- First it will ask for a existing valid password, after that you have to input the new password.
  The old password will stay valid, as well.

If you want to add a keyfile (instead of a password) it would be
`sudo cryptsetup luksAddKey /dev/sda3 MyKeyFile.txt`

**Remove a password slot:**

- Possibility 1: `sudo cryptsetup luksRemoveKey /dev/sda3`
  => You have to enter the password which you want to delete (it will automatically find the correct password slot)
- Possibility 2: `sudo cryptsetup luksKillSlot /dev/sda3 2`
  => This will delete password slot 2 (you have to enter the password of any other password slot, but not of slot 2
  => This works even if you don't know the password of slot 2
- Possibility 3: `sudo cryptsetup luksRemoveKey --key-file MyKeyFile.txt /dev/sda3`
  => Removes the key file `MyKeyFile.txt` if it is valid

**See how many slots are active:**
`sudo cryptsetup luksDump /dev/sda3`
This will output all settings of luks for this partition.

**Test if a password is valid for the partition:**
`sudo cryptsetup open --verbose --test-passphrase /dev/sda3`
Now you can enter a password and it will tell you if it was wrong or to which password slot it belongs.
If you want to test if a KeyFile is valid it works like this:
`sudo cryptsetup open --verbose --test-passphrase --key-file MyKeyFile.txt /dev/sda3`

**Backup the header of a luks partition:**
`sudo cryptsetup luksHeaderBackup /dev/sda3 --header-backup-file MyLuksHeader.dat`
`sudo chmod +r MyLuksHeader.dat`
It will create a file of 16MB.
This is very important to save. If the header is damaged all data is lost without a backup!

**List all encrypted file systems:**
`sudo cat /etc/crypttab`

If you need more help you can type `man cryptsetup`.